# clicking "Go To Definition" - Why doesn't Visual Studio 2010 go to Object Browser like Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, go-to-definition

When clicking "Go To Definition" after right clicking a .NET object (of a standard .NET class type) in Visual Studio 2010, the Object Explorer doesn't come up like it did in Visual Studio 2008.  Object Browser was nice because it gave documentation (similar to MSDN) about that object's class.  In Visual Studio 2010, I get a shell version of the actual class instead.  But I have to expand/collapse the class members to read about the class member (ie Property, Method, Class, etc..).  How can I have Visual Studio 2010 link to MSDN or the Object Browser?

=========

## Update 8/22/2011 4:48pm

In these Visual Studio 2008 screen shots, I'm first right clicking "Boolean" and then choosing "Go To Definition".  Then it opens up "Object Explorer"

[image]

[image]

Comment: VS2008 worked this way too.  I can only guess you used to have an add-on that did this.

Comment: Perhaps linking to MSDN requires a VS add-on.  But without any add-ons, choosing "Go To Definition" used to open a new tab called "Object Browser".  I'll paste a screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.. the language was different when I tested.  They are consistent in both versions of Visual Studio if you use the same .NET language.

VB.NET displays the Object Browser

C#.NET displays the the source code class with signatures (no implementations)